# How to achieve large gain in the transfer function with OP-AMPs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

My transfer function is:

$$ \frac{-115.298}{1+5\centerdot10^{-4}s}$$

To achieve the denominator I used an inverting op-amp with Rf = 1k, Cf = 0.5uF (ceramic, and both in parallel) in feedback and R = 1k at the input. I am using TL084 OP-AMP.But is it possible to get a large gain of 115.298 in any possible way? Can any one suggest any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The -3dB cutoff frequency of your transfer function is roughly at 200Hz and the TL084 has a gain-bandwidth product of 3MHz. So, a gain of -115 is achievable because 200*115=23000 which is hundred times less than 3MHz (the recommended margin to ensure a good working of the amplifier is ten times less).

The bandpass gain is given by the ratio of R2 and R1 (G=-R2/R1). The cut-off frequency is given by R2 and C (f=1/(2*pi*R2*C). So you can use R1 = 1k, R2=120k and C=6.8nF
This gives a gain of -120 and a cut-off frequency at 195Hz.

You can then adjust these values using other components if you want to get closer to the transfer function you want to achieve.

Comment: If you're going to talk about specific components in a circuit, you need to show us the circuit.

Comment: I don't talk about specific components. I just say that if the aim is to get closer to 115.298 for the gain and obtain the exact cut-off frequency, then the value of R1, R2 and C must be adjusted. I gave standard and easy to find values but there are many other values (see http://ieee.ucsd.edu/wiki/_media/tutorials/standard_resistor_and_capaciter_values.pdf)

Comment: Then what are R1, R2 and C? How are they connected? I have a pretty good idea of what you're talking about, because I have a lot of experience. But the OP and any other newbies who come across this question will not. You need to make it clear.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I see what you mean.
In fact as the original question talked about "Rf, Cf and R", I supposed that user33632 knows some basics about opamps.
When I talk about R1, R2, and C I refer to the classical inverting amplifier configuration with a capacitor (C) in parallel with the feedback resistor.
Here is a link to a document from Texas Instrument which lists all "basic" opamp configurations : http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/AN-31.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "achieve" the denominator of the given gain function independent on the numerator (which gives the DC gain of the circuit). If you know the transfer function (gain) of an inverting opamp circuit with an R-C parallel combination in the feedback path (first-order lowpass) it is a simple task to find the corresponding parts values.

Comment: Unless you have two op amps

Comment: I want to upload a pdf document file here that i tried about this.How to do this?